# Documentation: requesting contributors' global dashboard or activity list akin to SO's front page

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, documentation

I hereby request a global dashboard, activity list, review queue, or something for Documentation that shows recent activity across all tags.  That way, proposed changes will be more visible at the time they are made.

The [front page of SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) lists questions generally starting from the most recently touched, across all tags.  This is nice because you see what folks are working on and can interact (mostly) live.

By contrast, the [front page of Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation) lists documentation by tag.  This is very useful for the person reading the documentation.  However, it means that *contributors* do not have the real-time visibility to proposed Documentation edits that they do to Q&A activity.

Could we have a page intended for the use of contributors that showed the most recent Documentation activity across all tags?

Comment: You may just get the whole tag removed by invoking the meta effect, considering some don't agree that tag should exist separate from the existing python tag...

Answer (score 1):

This was brought up in the private beta, and one of the ideas was to make a special dashboard where the data is pulled from tags that you choose (maybe auto selected based on tags that you have contributed to).

[image]

This could be extended to make it more tag agnostic (prefixing notifications with the tag name, for example).

Comment: I think that would work, and I especially like the auto-select.  I'm not sure which contributions you are referring to, but I would be interested in auto-select based on tags of Q&A contributions, or of both Q&A and Doc contribs, since at the moment I have very few Documentation contributions.

Comment: I was trying to say those items from areas that pull from multiple tags (such as the "Requested Topics" section) would tell you what tag they came from ("Java - JVM Architecture", "Haskell - IO").